# Why does SSL_get_error return SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, winsock2

I attempt to perform an HTTP GET request via winsock2 usin openssl 1.1.1 as SSL Layer:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define FAIL    -1

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

SOCKET OpenConnection(char* hostname, char* port)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo* ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    printf("\nInitializing Winsock");
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    return ConnectSocket;
}


SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); 
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1);
    
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}


void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509* cert;
    char* line;
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if (cert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        //free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        //free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    } else {
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
    } 
}

void releaseSocket( SSL_CTX* ctx, int server)
{
    /* close socket */
    closesocket(server);   
    /* release context */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Initializing Connection");
    char buf[1024];
    char acClientRequest[1024] = { 0 };

    SSL_library_init();
    char* hostname = "google.com";
    char* portnum = "443";

    SSL_CTX* ctx = InitCTX();
    int server = OpenConnection(hostname, portnum);
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */


    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    } else {
        const char* cpRequestMessage = "GET / HTTP 1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.54.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n";

        printf("\n\nConnected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
       
        /* get any certs */
        ShowCerts(ssl);   
        /* encrypt & send message */
        printf("REQUEST:\n\n%s\n",cpRequestMessage);
        SSL_write(ssl, acClientRequest, strlen(acClientRequest));  

        /* get reply & decrypt */
        int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
        int error = SSL_get_error(ssl,bytes);
        switch (error)
        {
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                puts("SSL ERROR SSL");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                puts("SSL ERROR SYSCALL");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC_JOB:
                puts("SSL ERROR WANT ASYNC_LOOKUP");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC:
                puts("SSL ERROR WANT X509_LOOKUP");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
                puts("SSL ERROR WANT X509_LOOKUP");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                puts("SSL ERROR WANT WRITE");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                puts("SSL ERROR WANT READ");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                puts("SSL ERROR SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN");
                releaseSocket(ctx,server);
                return 1;
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }
        puts("RESPONSE\n");
        for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
            putchar(buf[i]);
        }
        
        /* release connection state */
        SSL_free(ssl);       
    }

    /* close socket */
    closesocket(server);   
    /* release context */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Whilst I run it via `cmd` I get the following error:

```
Initializing Connection
Initializing Winsock

Connected with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 encryption
Server certificates:
Subject: /OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
Issuer: /OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
REQUEST:

GET / HTTP 1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Connection: close
Accept: */*


SSL ERROR SYSCALL
```

The error `SSL ERROR SYSCALL` according to the code above means that `SSL_get_error` returns the `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. But I have trouble on diagnosing the reason.

The first thing that I did was to use sslyze:

```
$ docker run --rm -it nablac0d3/sslyze:5.0.0 www.google.com
Unable to find image 'nablac0d3/sslyze:5.0.0' locally
5.0.0: Pulling from nablac0d3/sslyze
eff15d958d66: Pull complete 
16dc372daf37: Pull complete 
509d5831bcf5: Pull complete 
72742266298b: Pull complete 
ba03a8977ca9: Pull complete 
8c15f448a534: Pull complete 
ef94aa21ac3e: Pull complete 
48214524924f: Pull complete 
b3e45cda18ec: Pull complete 
4220edb8d370: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6e4a25153507f8f2eed3ee232d7ae8ebed978d5923799ca3977e82912f3b5f77
Status: Downloaded newer image for nablac0d3/sslyze:5.0.0

 CHECKING CONNECTIVITY TO SERVER(S)
 ----------------------------------

   www.google.com:443        => 172.217.17.196 

 SCAN RESULTS FOR WWW.GOOGLE.COM:443 - 172.217.17.196
 ----------------------------------------------------

 * Certificates Information:
       Hostname sent for SNI:             www.google.com
       Number of certificates detected:   2


     Certificate #0 ( _EllipticCurvePublicKey )
       SHA1 Fingerprint:                  60c9b43a60d44f363641731cfa42c03a3a3cdc5b
       Common Name:                       www.google.com
       Issuer:                            GTS CA 1C3
       Serial Number:                     208743615106412169146553081758012741296
       Not Before:                        2022-06-27
       Not After:                         2022-09-19
       Public Key Algorithm:              _EllipticCurvePublicKey
       Signature Algorithm:               sha256
       Key Size:                          256
       Curve:                             secp256r1
       DNS Subject Alternative Names:     ['www.google.com']

     Certificate #0 - Trust
       Hostname Validation:               OK - Certificate matches server hostname
       Android CA Store (12.0.0_r3):      OK - Certificate is trusted
       Apple CA Store (iOS 15, iPadOS 15, macOS 12, tvOS 15, and watchOS 8):OK - Certificate is trusted
       Java CA Store (jdk-13.0.2):        OK - Certificate is trusted
       Mozilla CA Store (2021-09-25):     OK - Certificate is trusted
       Windows CA Store (2021-09-25):     OK - Certificate is trusted
       Symantec 2018 Deprecation:         OK - Not a Symantec-issued certificate
       Received Chain:                    www.google.com --> GTS CA 1C3 --> GTS Root R1
       Verified Chain:                    www.google.com --> GTS CA 1C3 --> GTS Root R1
       Received Chain Contains Anchor:    OK - Anchor certificate not sent
       Received Chain Order:              OK - Order is valid
       Verified Chain contains SHA1:      OK - No SHA1-signed certificate in the verified certificate chain

     Certificate #0 - Extensions
       OCSP Must-Staple:                  NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found
       Certificate Transparency:          WARNING - Only 2 SCTs included but Google recommends 3 or more

     Certificate #0 - OCSP Stapling
                                          NOT SUPPORTED - Server did not send back an OCSP response


     Certificate #1 ( _RSAPublicKey )
       SHA1 Fingerprint:                  b7bfe0030b69e712368e65d2c3c0c51f0b643c3b
       Common Name:                       www.google.com
       Issuer:                            GTS CA 1C3
       Serial Number:                     210362545992136918327962384234505396292
       Not Before:                        2022-06-27
       Not After:                         2022-09-19
       Public Key Algorithm:              _RSAPublicKey
       Signature Algorithm:               sha256
       Key Size:                          2048
       Exponent:                          65537
       DNS Subject Alternative Names:     ['www.google.com']

     Certificate #1 - Trust
       Hostname Validation:               OK - Certificate matches server hostname
       Android CA Store (12.0.0_r3):      OK - Certificate is trusted
       Apple CA Store (iOS 15, iPadOS 15, macOS 12, tvOS 15, and watchOS 8):OK - Certificate is trusted
       Java CA Store (jdk-13.0.2):        OK - Certificate is trusted
       Mozilla CA Store (2021-09-25):     OK - Certificate is trusted
       Windows CA Store (2021-09-25):     OK - Certificate is trusted
       Symantec 2018 Deprecation:         OK - Not a Symantec-issued certificate
       Received Chain:                    www.google.com --> GTS CA 1C3 --> GTS Root R1
       Verified Chain:                    www.google.com --> GTS CA 1C3 --> GTS Root R1
       Received Chain Contains Anchor:    OK - Anchor certificate not sent
       Received Chain Order:              OK - Order is valid
       Verified Chain contains SHA1:      OK - No SHA1-signed certificate in the verified certificate chain

     Certificate #1 - Extensions
       OCSP Must-Staple:                  NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found
       Certificate Transparency:          WARNING - Only 2 SCTs included but Google recommends 3 or more

     Certificate #1 - OCSP Stapling
                                          NOT SUPPORTED - Server did not send back an OCSP response

 * SSL 2.0 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 7 cipher suites; the server rejected all cipher suites.

 * SSL 3.0 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 80 cipher suites; the server rejected all cipher suites.

 * TLS 1.0 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 80 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 5 cipher suites:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                     168                      
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)

     The group of cipher suites supported by the server has the following properties:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       Legacy RC4 Algorithm               OK - Not Supported


 * TLS 1.1 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 80 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 5 cipher suites:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                     168                      
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)

     The group of cipher suites supported by the server has the following properties:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       Legacy RC4 Algorithm               OK - Not Supported


 * TLS 1.2 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 156 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 11 cipher suites:
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                   256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                      256                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256                   128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                      128                      
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA                     168                      
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256       256       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384             256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                256       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256             128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                128       ECDH: prime256v1 (256 bits)
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256     256       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)

     The group of cipher suites supported by the server has the following properties:
       Forward Secrecy                    OK - Supported
       Legacy RC4 Algorithm               OK - Not Supported


 * TLS 1.3 Cipher Suites:
     Attempted to connect using 5 cipher suites.

     The server accepted the following 3 cipher suites:
        TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256                      256       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)
        TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                            256       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)
        TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256                            128       ECDH: X25519 (253 bits)


 * Deflate Compression:
                                          OK - Compression disabled

 * OpenSSL CCS Injection:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable to OpenSSL CCS injection

 * OpenSSL Heartbleed:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable to Heartbleed

 * ROBOT Attack:
                                          OK - Not vulnerable.

 * Session Renegotiation:
       Client Renegotiation DoS Attack:   OK - Not vulnerable
       Secure Renegotiation:              OK - Supported

 * Elliptic Curve Key Exchange:
       Supported curves:                  X25519, prime256v1
       Rejected curves:                   X448, prime192v1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, secp224k1, secp224r1, secp256k1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect163k1, sect163r1, sect163r2, sect193r1, sect193r2, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect239k1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1

 SCANS COMPLETED IN 7.110242 S
 -----------------------------

 COMPLIANCE AGAINST MOZILLA TLS CONFIGURATION
 --------------------------------------------

    Checking results against Mozilla's "intermediate" configuration. See https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ for more details.

    www.google.com:443: FAILED - Not compliant.
        * tls_versions: TLS versions {'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1'} are supported, but should be rejected.
        * ciphers: Cipher suites {'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256', 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'} are supported, but should be rejected.
```

TLS 1.3 is supported. And according to my attempt I use TLS1.3, therefore AFAIK it seems not to be an wrong TLS version issue. Also the host is able to connect into google.com via network according to ping:

```
PING google.com (142.250.184.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=21.8 ms
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=22.0 ms
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=114 time=21.4 ms
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=5 ttl=114 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from sof02s43-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.184.142): icmp_seq=6 ttl=114 time=21.6 ms
^C^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.484/21.957/22.385/0.355 ms
```

Therefore, why I still get the error despite being able to perform an Https call to google.com?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the error is because you provide the request from a variable from a zeroed table named `acClientRequest` at:

```
    char acClientRequest[1024] = { 0 };
```

The request is performed like this:

```
SSL_write(ssl, acClientRequest, strlen(acClientRequest));
```

But it must be performed like that:

```
SSL_write(ssl, cpRequestMessage, strlen(cpRequestMessage));
```

Instead.